# Laplacian Equation Proof using Spherical Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I have been working at this problem for hours and I have made no progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQIfG.png)

I feel like I am applying the chain rule incorrectly here and it is not leading me to the correct answer.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: https://planetmath.org/derivationofthelaplacianfromrectangulartosphericalcoordinates